# How do I get a list of "work or school" acounts connected to my Windows 10 (and Windows 11) device using cmd or PowerShell?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe, windows-11

I have a few "work or school" accounts connected to my Windows 10 personal device. Is there a way to get a list of these accounts using cmd or PowerShell?

There's `dsregcmd /listaccounts` in the recent Windows 11 insider builds but I am looking for a solution that works out of the box on Windows 10 and Windows 11 21H2 also.

On Windows 10 (21H2) and Windows 11 (21H2), I don't see `/listaccounts` switch on `dsregcmd` help.

**Windows 10 (21H2)**:

```
cmd> ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1645]

cmd> dsregcmd /?
DSREGCMD switches
                        /? : Displays the help message for DSREGCMD
                   /status : Displays the device join status
               /status_old : Displays the device join status in old format
                     /join : Schedules and monitors the Autojoin task to Hybrid Join the device
                    /leave : Performs Hybrid Unjoin
                    /debug : Displays debug messages
               /refreshprt : Refreshes PRT in the CloudAP cache

cmd>
```

**Windows 11 (21H2)**:

```
cmd> ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.613]

cmd> dsregcmd /?
DSREGCMD switches
                        /? : Displays the help message for DSREGCMD
                   /status : Displays the device join status
               /status_old : Displays the device join status in old format
                     /join : Schedules and monitors the Autojoin task to Hybrid Join the device
                    /leave : Performs Hybrid Unjoin
                    /debug : Displays debug messages
               /refreshprt : Refreshes PRT in the CloudAP cache

cmd>
```

**Windows 11 Insider build** (has `/listaccounts` switch):

```
cmd>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22598.200]

cmd>dsregcmd /?
DSREGCMD switches
                        /? : Displays the help message for DSREGCMD
                   /status : Displays the device join status
               /status_old : Displays the device join status in old format
                     /join : Schedules and monitors the Autojoin task to Hybrid Join the device
                    /leave : Performs Hybrid Unjoin
                    /debug : Displays debug messages
               /refreshprt : Refreshes PRT in the CloudAP cache
          /refreshp2pcerts : Refreshes P2P certificates
          /cleanupaccounts : Deletes all WAM accounts
             /listaccounts : Lists all WAM accounts
             /UpdateDevice : Update device attributes to Azure AD

cmd>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "connected"?

Comment: @DavidPostill Add a Work or School account, like [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security/zero-trust/media/screenshot-access-work-school-settings.png)

Comment: I wanted to suggest `dsregcmd /status` but that only shows the account provider, not the actual account name.

Comment: @user1686 There's `dsregcmd /listaccounts` that I am seeing in the recent Windows 11 insider builds, but I am looking for a solution that works on Windows 10 also.

Comment: @Ramhound It doesn't on my Windows 10 (21H2) device. I have updated the question with what I see on that installation.

Answer (score 2):

here is my idea for windows 10. simply copy/paste this function to a powershell-console and execute it. it will read out the WorkplaceThumbprint and search for it in Registry. If an Account exists, in Registry-Hive the UserEmail can be found.

```
function CheckForBusinessOrSchoolAccount {
    $x=(dsregcmd /status | select-string -Pattern "WorkplaceThumbprint" | out-string).Trim()

    switch (!$x) {
        $true {
            Write-Host "No Business/School-Account found on this Host"
        }
        $false {
            $y=$x.LastIndexOf(":")
            $AccountThumbPrint=$x.Substring($y+2)
            $AccountMailAddress=(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WorkplaceJoin\JoinInfo\$AccountThumbPrint" -Name UserEmail | select UserEmail | ft -HideTableHeaders | out-string).Trim()

            Write-Host "We found an existing Account with Thumbprint $AccountThumbPrint and Mail-Address $AccountMailAddress."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the command "dsregcmd /status" mentioned at initial question, is able to get the thumbprint of an existing school/business-account.

in registry HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WorkplaceJoin\JoinInfo\<ThumbPrint> the Mailaddress of the account can be found (Name -UserEmail).

this function reads the thumbprint and searches for it in registry, pipes out the mailaddress for the school/business-account.